# Why is my initial ngrx state not working with a ngIf

Tags: angular, ngrx

I've an angular app, and I'm setting up ngrx.

In one of my component, I register to the change of one value(if authenticated or not):

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.isAuth$ = this.store.select(fromRoot.getIsAuthenticated);
    this.isAuth$.subscribe((v) => console.log('new auth ', v));
}
```

When I load the page, I get the new auth false(as expected).

What is weird is that the view of this component has two element, one is displayed when true, the other when false:

```
<div>
    <div class="layout-profile" [ngClass]="{'layout-profile-active':active}" *ngIf="(isAuth$ | async)">
        <a href="#" (click)="onClick($event)" class="layout-profile-button">
            <img src="assets/layout/images/avatar.png" alt="babylon-layout" />
            <div class="layout-profile-userinfo">
                <span class="layout-profile-name">Arlene Welch</span>
                <span class="layout-profile-role">Design Ops</span>
            </div>
            <i class="layout-profile-icon pi pi-angle-down"></i>
        </a>
        <ul class="layout-profile-menu" [@menu]="active ? 'visible' : 'hidden'">
            <li role="menuitem">
                <a [routerLink]="['/user/profile']" [attr.tabindex]="!active ? '-1' : null">
                    <i class="pi pi-user"></i>
                    <span>Profile</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li role="menuitem">
                <a href="#" [attr.tabindex]="!active ? '-1' : null" (click)="logout($event)">
                    <i class="pi pi-sign-out"></i>
                    <span>Déconnexion</span>

                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="layout-profile" [ngClass]="{'layout-profile-active':active}" *ngIf="!(isAuth$ | async)">
        <ul class="layout-profile-menu" [@menu]="active ? 'visible' : 'hidden'">
            <li role="menuitem">
                <a [routerLink]="['/auth/login']" [attr.tabindex]="!active ? '-1' : null">
                    <i class="pi pi-user"></i>
                    <span>Connexion</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I refresh the page, and ONLY when I refresh the page, I see neither of them. Once the page is loaded, if I do some logout/login, the correct part of my component is displayed.

Any idea what is going on?

**EDIT**
Here is my App.reducer.ts if it helps:

```
import { ActionReducerMap, createFeatureSelector, createSelector } from '@ngrx/store';
import * as fromAuth from './auth/auth.reducer';

export interface State {
    auth: fromAuth.State;
}

export const reducers: ActionReducerMap<State> = {
    auth: fromAuth.authReducer
};
export const getAuthState = createFeatureSelector<fromAuth.State>('auth');
export const getIsAuthenticated = createSelector(getAuthState, fromAuth.getIsAuthenticated);
```

And the reducer of my app:

```
import { AuthActions, AuthActionTypes } from "./auth.actions";
import { User } from "firebase";

export interface State {
    isAuthenticated: boolean;
    user: User;
};

const initialState: State = {
    isAuthenticated: false,
    user: null
};

export function authReducer(state = initialState, action: AuthActions): State {
    switch (action.type) {
        case AuthActionTypes.SET_AUTHENTICATED: {
            return {
                isAuthenticated: true,
                user: action.user
            };
        }
        case AuthActionTypes.SET_UNAUTHENTICATED: {
            return {
                isAuthenticated: false,
                user: null
            };
        }

        default: {
            return state;
        }
    }
}
export const getIsAuthenticated = (state: State) => state.isAuthenticated;
```

Comment: What's the output of your `console.log`? Can you show more code? How `fromRoot.getIsAuthenticated` is defined and what does your initial state look like?

Comment: @pschild: It's like I would expect: First load it's false, then true when I validate the login form, then false again when I logout

Comment: @pschild I added the code of my reducers, do you see anything else that could help?

Comment: If the `console.log` prints the correct value then it sounds like there's something wrong with your change detection, causing the changes being not applied to the template. Are you using `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` in your component?

Comment: Honestly, it's my first angular app, so I've not changed this. Where should it be specified?

Comment: You can specify it in the `@Component` decorator. You can read more about it [here](https://blog.angular-university.io/how-does-angular-2-change-detection-really-work/) or [here](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectionStrategy) if you want, but if you didn't change anything that should not be the problem.

Comment: You're saying that you see neither of your two elements. Directly after initial loading, can you inspect your HTML with your browser's devtools and confirm that really nothing is rendered? I see you're also working with an `active` property that seems to impact the visibility of your elements, maybe this simply hides the content. But it's just guessing. Is it possible that you recreate this issue with a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/fork/angular)?

Comment: I've checked, I've added one `<span>test</span> just above my 2 conditionals tests. I see it and just below I've two `<!-- bindings={...}-->`: https://www.screencast.com/t/8cp9UtjlqSd

I will try to replicate in stackblitz, but honestly, that is real hardwork. I'm using a NgPrime template, so I've to replicate a lot of things to come to this point